# Temporary Security Credentials - How to get access, given a role name & AWS account id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli

AWS documentation provides multiple approach, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html).

---

In our environment, we have multiple AWS accounts.

Usage scenario is to switch between AWS accounts and run AWS cli commands from laptop, as part of automation.

Before  running AWS cli command on a specific AWS account, we need to get temporary credentials for that account, given account id.

Getting access to(by switching over) multiple AWS accounts, helps us in automation.

---

Basically we would like to run some tool like `./some_aws_sdk_tool.py role_name aws_account_name`, assuming a `role_name` to get credentials.

I want to test this with my single AWS account(personal).

1) What are the steps to configure my AWS account to create such `role_name`?

2)
What is the approach to get temporary credentials to a specific `aws_account_name` with `some_aws_sdk_tool.py`? to be able run AWS CLI commands for n minutes..

Comment: You could have a set of credentials in one main account and you have IAM roles in the other accounts. You give the IAM principal in the main account permission to assume relevant IAM roles in the other accounts. That process gives you temporary credentials with the necessary permissions to operate in the other accounts.

Comment: @jarmod's statement here is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to do this from within your code or using the AWS CLI?

If you're using the CLI, the easiest way is to create profiles in your AWS credentials file, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html). Each profile identifies a role ARN and the source login information that is allowed to assume that role.

Alternatively, you can run the `sts assume-role` command, parse the results, and set environment variables:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/Example' --role-session-name 'some_unique_but_relevant_string'

{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "ASIAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "SecretAccessKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "SessionToken": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX//////////XXX...XXXXX",
        "Expiration": "2020-03-05T20:57:45Z"
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AROAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:some_unique_but_relevant_string",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/Example/some_unique_but_relevant_string"
    }
}
```

If you want to do it from within your program, you can use code like this:

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

role_arn = "..."
session_name = "some_unique_but_relevant_value"

response = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn=role_arn,
    RoleSessionName=session_name
)
creds = response['Credentials']

actual_client = boto3.client('SERVICE',
    aws_access_key_id=creds['AccessKeyId']
    aws_secret_access_key=creds['SecretAccessKey']
    aws_session_token=creds['SessionToken'])
```

Comment: Either AWS CLI or SDK is fine for me. Both will allow to automate

Comment: How does this role `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/Example` look like, in term of polcies(access)? Because this role should allow to read/write every resource in that aws account?

Comment: @overexchange - it's whatever you want to allow. If you want full access, you can attached the `AdministratorAccess` managed policy. More important is who you allow to assume the role, which is a usually a combination of a trust policy on the role and an `sts:AssumeRole` policy attached to users/roles in the parent account.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. You can only see a secret key on the first time it gets created, AWS will never show it to you again. [See more here](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/security/wheres-my-secret-access-key/).

Some Identity Managers like [Okta](https://www.okta.com/) allow you to assume roles on CLI so you don't have to deal with credentials directly. You just assign a role to an user and he will be able to assume the role directly after the first login.

Comment: At my previous company, I used a boto aws sdk python tool(they wrote) to retrieve and store the access key in `~/.aws/credentials` we did something like: `./get_aws_key.py account_name`. All the setup in AWS was accessed through okta. We had two roles(readonly & rw) for every AWS account, as a user.

Comment: So you were not retrieving the keys from AWS, but from another sources. Anyway, that is not a good practice.

Comment: **1)** How do we automate the process to access multiple AWS accounts to run AWS CLI commands across accounts? Because we need credentials before running AWS CLI.... irrespective of usage of tools like okta. **2)** Why it is not a good practice?

Comment: 1) Each user should be held responsible for its own set of credentials. You don't need to give the user permissions to resources, but can tell which roles they can assume. So, he will just need to add the role arn to the local aws cli configuration and he will be able to assume that role when calling the CLI. You can have that user on AWS IAM or use an identety manager like okta. 

2) Because you should not have sensitive information bundled around.